# Run another python script without a popup cmd prompt and not in a sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, exec

Problem with `os.system("script2.py 1")` is that it pops up a black cmd prompt momenterally :/

Problems with `exec("script2.py 1")` is that it waits in sequence...

Any alternatives?

Comment: It might also be worth a look at the subprocess module, which handles ways to execute system commands - http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @PatrickKostjens How?

Comment: @joeButler Looks interesting, didn't know about that :S

Comment: Note that with subprocess you can redirect the output and error streams. I've never used this on Windows, but I think you will be able to hide what you don't want the user to see.

Comment: @joeButler Yeah, looks exactly what I need especially the error streams. I however can't get it working right atm :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess` is where you should be looking specifically `Popen`.

i.e.:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["script2.py", "1"])
```

or

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py", "1"])
```

You have a lot of control over what goes on including hiding windows.

Comment: To suppress the cmd console window, change the extension to `.pyw` for the first way or use `"pythonw"` instead of `"python"` in the second.

Comment: `pythonw` only exists on windows AFAIK.